# Splash Screen Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, splash-screen

I actually try to add a Splash Screen to my WPF application. It is quite easy:

```
SplashScreen s = new SplashScreen("/Images/Agrar.png");
s.Show(true);
```

My problem is, that I want the Splash Screen to show about 10sec, but my Application doesn´t need so long to load.

So I thought about the Timer class and tried a bit, but I don´t know how to combine it with a Splash Screen. 
Is there a better solution? How does it work with Timer? Because I didn´t find a option to say, what should happen while the Timer is running.

Comment: Why would you unnecessarily force a splash screen on the users?

Comment: It should be a type of advertisement...

Comment: "that I want the Splash Screen to show about 10sec" -> are you sure you really want to do that? There is nothing more annoying when a application starts than a splash screen

Comment: Ok, I think 10 seconds are a bit overdone but yes, I want to show it for a few seconds..

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C try have a look at this, might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try putting your main thread to sleep for 10 seconds (if splash is visible, users won't use your app anyway), or fade out the splash over a period of time:

```
    SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("/Images/Agrar.png");
    splash.Show(false);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    splash.Close( TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); //fade out over 20 seconds
```

Comment: I really don't think a `Thread.Sleep` is a good idea... Displaying a splash screen is already something annoying, but if you "lock" your application with a `Thread.Sleep` so it can't even do some useful job such as resource loading in the background while annoying the user... >___<

Comment: `Task.Delay` is the preferred alternative to `Thread.Sleep`, as it is asynchronous and will not block the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The best way and using the API is

```
  SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splashscreen.jpg");
  splash.Show(false);
  splash.Close(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2));
  InitializeComponent();
```