# How to make Timer stop and Form appears in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I did one Form Splash Screen,that after the Timer Tick appears the Form Principal.

**And my code It's something like that :**

```
pbLoad = ProgressBar
timer1 = Timer Tick

if (pbLoad.value < 100) 
{
    pbLoad.value = pbLoad.Value + 2;
}
else 
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

When i put to Start the code,I can't edit because don't let me edit,and the Timer Tick won't pass from that part,the Load Screen,and I can't see my Form.

**PS : I will post late,the screenshot.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splash Screen Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279769/splash-screen-timer)

Comment: Did you remember to set an interval for your timer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with the first execution of the Tick or Elapsed event handler. A good time would be something like a second or two, so the user can view the splash screen.When that happen, you can close your window and open the new one, or just hide it. You can use whether Hide() or Close() methods.

```
    private void tmrMain_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrMain.Stop();

        frmMain main = new frmMain();
        main.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void frmSplash_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrMain.Start();
    }
```